# How can I get notification whever my EC2 instance down?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have 3 EC2 instances running php laravel web. Sometimes, one of them is over load and down. I have to restart it manually.

I've configured prometheus agent and grafana to monitor metrics and logs. Now I want to get notification when my instances is over 90% CPU. But, prometheus agent cannot send metrics to grafana.

How can I configure to receive email in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can active alertmanager and install it and config rule

then you must pass the query to check is up or not

the query you need is `up == 0` to check when if your server is down alert to you with many ways [all ways to send alert](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/#:%7E:text=The%20Alertmanager%20handles%20alerts%20sent,silencing%20and%20inhibition%20of%20alerts.)

config rules:

```
      - alert: InstanceDown
          Condition for alerting
        expr: up == 0
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity : critical
          value : "{{ $value }}"
        annotations:
          title: "server {{ $labels.instance }} down"
          description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 1 minute."
```